# Please fix VBA error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code with comments indicating where the code doesn't perform the correct function. I would like it to display all available employees; I have 3 text boxes, but it only displays in 2 of 3 boxes when 3 employees are present. If there are more than 2 employees I need all employees to be shown in the msg box. Currently, only a max of 2 is shown. Would you please help me with the following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox9_data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, l, m, n As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim o
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee ID")
    l = 2
    With UserForm1
        m = ws.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
        If Trim(.TextBox4.Value) = "" Or Trim(.TextBox5.Value) = "" Or Trim(.ComboBox3.Value) = "" Then
            .TextBox9.Value = ""
            .TextBox10.Value = ""
            Exit Sub
        Else

            For i = l To m
                If UCase(Trim(ws.Range("B" & i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(.TextBox4.Value)) And _
                   UCase(Trim(ws.Range("D" & i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(.TextBox5.Value)) And _
                   UCase(Trim(ws.Range("E" & i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(.ComboBox3.Value)) Then

                    If dict.Exists(Trim(ws.Range("H" & i))) Then
                    Else
                        dict(Trim(ws.Range("H" & i))) = "" ' Does not display all imployees. Curently only displays max of 2
                        dict1(Trim(ws.Range("H" & i))) = Trim(ws.Range("H" & i)) & "-" & Trim(ws.Range("I" & i)) & " " & Trim(ws.Range("J" & i)) ' Does not display all imployees. Curently only displays max of 2
                    End If
                    If dict.count > 1 Then
                        MsgBox ("Two or more employees have worked on this. Investigate who is at fault.") & _
                                vbCrLf & "Total employees found: " & dict.count _
                              & vbLf & Join(dict1.Items, vbLf) ' Needs to display the total of qty of employees and list all of them. Currently only displays a max of 2
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If dict.count = 0 Then
                .TextBox9.Value = ""
                .TextBox10.Value = ""
                .TextBox17.Value = ""
            ElseIf dict.count = 1 Then
                .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
                .TextBox10.Value = ""
                .TextBox17.Value = ""
            ElseIf dict.count = 2 Then           ' Added additional "if" statement - This statement doesnt work
                .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
                .TextBox10.Value = dict.Keys()(1)
                .TextBox17.Value = ""            ' Added additional box for employee #3 - This box doesn't display
            Else
                .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
                .TextBox10.Value = dict.Keys()(1)
                .TextBox17.Value = dict.Keys()(2)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am going to assume that you actually have code that does not have statements split over separate lines with a line continuation character. If I am incorrect please rollback the edit.

Comment: You say the code runs which is why I have assumed split statements like  If Trim(.TextBox4.Value) = "" Or Trim(.TextBox5.Value) = "" Or 
    Trim(.ComboBox3.Value) = "" Then      were actually on one line before pasting.   Apart from that, have you stepped through the code with F8 to check your logic for when 3 are present? Checking conditions are met and expected path taken?

Comment: in my opinion, "dict" is only counting up 2 and not all. I need dict to look at all available possibilities based on the Text Box4, 5, and ComboBox 3 criteria and report back. If dict.count is >1 then display a message with all available data (in this case employees and employee numbers)

Comment: I moved "If dict.count > 1 Then" statement to the bottom of the code, and that seems to solve the problem, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this?

```
      If dict.Count > 2 Then
            .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
            .TextBox10.Value = dict.Keys()(1)
            .TextBox17.Value = dict.Keys()(2)
        ElseIf dict.Count = 2 Then
           .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
            .TextBox10.Value = dict.Keys()(1)
            .TextBox17.Value = ""
        ElseIf dict.Count = 1 Then
             .TextBox9.Value = dict.Keys()(0)
            .TextBox10.Value = ""
            .TextBox17.Value = ""
        Else
            .TextBox9.Value = ""
            .TextBox10.Value = ""
            .TextBox17.Value = ""
        End If
```